# Can I send and execute mongoose virtuals with such construction on a client side?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose

I have really complicated logic for getters and setters, which works fine on the server side. I want to be able use it on the client, but instead of my functions I'm getting empty object.
If it is important, I'm using Anguar 1.5 on the client and node 4.3 on the server.

```
DataSchema.virtual('data.items').get(function () {
  let getOneByTime = (time) => {
    ...
  };

  let setOneByTime = (duration, time) => {
    ...
  };

  let get = () => {
    ...
  };

  let set = (inputDurations) => {
    ...
  };

  return {
    getOneByTime: getOneByTime,
    setOneByTime: setOneByTime,
    get: get,
    set: set
  };
});
```

Or, maybe it is possible to use `DataSchema.methods` with nested objects?

```
DataSchema.methods.data.items.set = () => {
  ... 
};
```